devise with 1 model and 2 registration forms
I am working on a booking app (like airbnb) where users can list their homes, and receive booking inquiries from other users.
There is a single User model, which can have different roles: host, guest, admin.
For this app, I want to display different registration pages for hosts and for guests.
Can I achieve that easily using devise ?
So far, I got a working solution, but it looks over complicated, and I'm pretty sure I am missing something.
# routes.rb

devise_for :users
devise_for :users, path_prefix: 'hosts', module: 'hosts', as: 'hosts', only: [:registrations]

# registrations_controller.rb

class Hosts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  # copying most of the parent logic
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      # copy of parent logic
      ...
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      # ---> custom logic 
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

end


As documented here you can nest your devise controllers by using devise_for method inside a namespace:
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]

namespace :host do
  devise_for :users, only: [:registrations]
end

namespace :guest do
  devise_for :users, only: [:registrations]
end

It will generate routes you need:

POST /host/users  -> Host::RegistrationsController#create
POST /guest/users -> Guest::RegistrationsController#create
etc.


it's almost working, however the devise mapping will be host_user, and my app checks for the user mapping

devise_scope helped me achieve this:
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'hosts/sign_up', to: 'host/registrations#new'
    post 'hosts/sign_up', to: 'host/registrations#create'
  end


